# Issue while pointing app installation directory other than C:\ drive

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008

I have dual boot system with Windows7 64-bit Professional edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition. The Win7 is installed on C:\ drive while Win2008R2 is installed on H:\ drive. My problem is, while installing applications in Win2008 especially SQLServer and VS.NET 2010, the installer copies some files to C:\ drive instead of H:\, this happens even if I specify a different path.

Please help me to sort this out.

Regards
Abraham

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bottom of this page for SQLServer:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx

No idea about VS.Net. Sorry. Although some installers have setup.ini files that you can adjust accordingly, not sure if this is true for VS.net